# how to get back YDN-DB options passed on creation of DB

Tags: encryption, crypt, ydn-db

i have a project and in some places i need to use the key passed for encryption.
i have this:

```
            schema = {
                stores: [store_schema_dominios, store_schema_fechas, store_schema_servidores]
            };

            var options = {
                Encryption: {
                    //expiration: 1000*15, //  optional data expiration in ms.
                    secrets: [{
                        name: 'usuario',
                        key: 'SOME KEY'
                    }]
                }
            };

            db2 = new ydn.db.Storage(nombreBase,schema,options);
```

is there some method to get back the 'SOME KEY' back like:

```
        db2.getSchema(function(schema) {
            console.log(schema); //this return the Schema
        });
```

i need something like this:

```
        db2.getOptions(function(options) {
            console.log(options);
        });
```

i need to re use the Crypt KEY

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue on https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/issues?status=new&status=open

Yes, it should able to get back what is set.